# Mismatch or Range error

Tags: excel, vba, macos, range, excel-2008

The code below gives either Mismatch or Range error in Excel 2008. How do I fix it?

```
Sub PEC()
    Dim PEC As String, result As Integer
    PEC = Range("AE2:AE26848").Value    
    If PEC = "A.06" Then result = 1    
    Range("AO2:AO26848").Value = result
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You cannot get a value from a range greater than one cell.

Comment: I am trying to have "1" put into a cell if "A.06" is in a different column, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PEC()
    For x = 2 to 26848
        If Range("AE" & x) = "A.06" Then Range("AO" & x) = 1
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the following code. It might seem more complicated, but it certainly does a better and more robust job. It is simply assigning your input and output ranges as SrcRng and DstRng.  FIND method for ranges is a good way to check for specific values.

> Sub PEC()
>
> ```
> Dim SrcRng As Range
> Dim DstRng As Range
> Dim rcell As Range
>
> Set SrcRng = Range ("AE2:AE26848")
> Set DstRng = Range("AO2:AO26848")
>
> Set rcell = SrcRng.Find(what:="A.06", after:=SrcRng.Cells(1, 1), _
>                     LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
>                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
>
> If Not rcell Is Nothing Then
>     DstRng.Value = 1
> End If
> ```
>
> End Sub